# How i can develop spring web application with application server inside?

Tags: java, spring, jar, jetty, application-server

I want to do this case, but don't know which way i have to choose: 
Launch JAR file will launch Application Server on 8080 port and deploy my web-application to application server. How i can do this? Which way better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). The feature is called as `Embedded`.
Spring Boot supports: Tomcat, Jetty, and Undertow servers